# Make diffrent V-MODEL on every index that i generate

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### How can I have different V-MODEL on every object that i generate

I am trying to make an sample cupcake website that can generate multiple forms in one submit.

But when I generate 2 field, the inputs of the 2 generated field bound by each other inputs.

This is the code I am trying to generate:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="cupcakes.push(def)">Add Cup Cake</button>

    <div v-for="(cupcake, index) in cupcakes" :key="index">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].name">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].description">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].type">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].prize">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].color">
    </div>

    <button @click="onSubmit">Create Cupcate</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cupcakes: [],
      def: {
        name: '',
        description: 'Originals',
        type: 'small',
        prize: 500,
        color: 'color'
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.cupcakes);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to do other things but it doesn't work.

How can I dis bind the 2 field and when I submit it will take the inputs that I type or input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing n times the same objet (def) into your cupcakes Array. `def` is a reference to an object. So when you update `cupcakes[n]`, you are just updating the `def` values.

What you need to do is send a copy of that object into the cupcakes object:

```
<button @click="cupcakes.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(def)))">Add Cup Cake</button>
```

I think a better pattern would be to make a method that returns you a new cupcake:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="cupcakes.push(getNewCupcake())">Add Cup Cake</button>

    <div v-for="(cupcake, index) in cupcakes" :key="index">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].name">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].description">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].type">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].prize">
      <input type="text" v-model="cupcakes[index].color">
    </div>

    <button @click="onSubmit">Create Cupcate</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cupcakes: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.cupcakes);
    },
    getNewCupcake() {
      return {
        name: "",
        description: "Originals",
        type: "small",
        prize: 500,
        color: "color"
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: can I modify the data in array using `map()` method?